# pre-increment and post-increment in C

Tags: c

First of all, I would like to apologize, if this question has been asked before in this forum. I searched, but could't find any similar problem.

I am a beginner in C. I was going through a tutorial and came across a code, the solution of which I can't understand.

Here is the code -

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define PRODUCT(x) (x*x)

int main()
{
    int i=3, j, k;

    j = PRODUCT(i++);
    k = PRODUCT(++i);

    return 1;
}
```

I tried running the code through compiler and got the solution as "j = 12" and "k = 49".

I know how #define works. It replace every occurrence of PRODUCT(x) by (x*x), but what I can't grasp is how j and k got the values 12 and 49, respectively.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: NOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO!

Comment: 'I searched, but could't find any similar problem.' REALLY?

Comment: "I can't grasp is how j and k got the values" - neither can your code, so you're in good company. Thus the nature of *undefined behavior*.

Comment: @Ashish -Wall when compile

Comment: Hurry up and close before any more rep-PersonalServicesWorkers show up:(

Comment: Thank you, Philip for pointing me to the related thread.

Comment: If that code came from a tutorial then you need to find a better tutorial.

Answer (score 4):

Your code will invoke undefined behavior. Anything could happen. The macro in statements

```
j = PRODUCT(i++);
k = PRODUCT(++i);
```

will be expanded to

```
j = x++ * x++;
k = ++x * ++x;
```

In both statements `x` is being modified more than once between two sequence points.

Comment: ...and that goes into my  'Rep-PersonalServicesWorker of the Month' bookmanrks.

Comment: @MartinJames; Well I already got your comment on the question. No need to repeat here. I am not taking it offensive anyway. Different people different shades.